# How to remove blue flares representing the end of the scrolling in webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm building a hybrid app using webview and when scrolling ends in the webview, there is a blue light representing the end of scrolling:

[image: sample blue flare]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your WebView xml layout:

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

You can also do it programatically by using:

```
webView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
```